# Menus not working in Nautilus

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, menu, bookmarks

In 12.04, after fresh start of Ubuntu OS, the bookmarks in Nautilus works fine.

But after a while, for some unknown reason, clicking any bookmarked directory doesn't take me to the bookmarked directory.

After another while, clicking the "Bookmarks" menu, it doesn't even show the drop-down list of bookmarked directories. Actually all the other menus `File`, `Edit`, `View`, `Go` and `Help` do not respond either.

So I wonder what has gone wrong?

Comment: What about menus of other programs like `Gedit`? If they are working fine then try reinstalling `Nautilus`: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus`

Comment: @BasharatSial: Thanks! Menus of other programs work fine. I reinstall Nautilus, but the problem remains.

Comment: I experience this same issue on and off. :-(

Comment: found bug reference in LaunchPad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/999827

Answer (score 2):

The bugpost above seems to offer a workaround:

```
$ killall nautilus
$ UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= nautilus
```

When I run these two commands nautilus reopens with the menus tied to the nautilus window. The menu elements seem to remain accessible.

Comment: Thanks! What does the second command mean? is `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` an environment variable?

Comment: Also how shal I run `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= nautilus` in a terminal, so that when the terminal is closed, nautilus is still running?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 12.10 and just calling `killall nautilus` so fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, Nautilus file manager menus are now at the top line of the desktop, not the top of your file manager window. Just move your mouse to the very top of your screen, and if you have a file manager window 'on top' then the file edit view help etc options appear at the very top of you desktop.

Having had a quick glance at it now, it seems that the very top line of the whole desktop is now 'context sensitive' so which ever of your many windows is 'on top' then placing the mouse at the top of the desktop will show you the correct menu options.

Comment: What do you mean by "Solved"? I have known that the menus are on the top of desktop.

Comment: I don't think this is solved at all. I have been a Unity user since it's inception and know how the menu's work but I am also getting the problem described above. When you select any of the menus in Nautilus they only display a very small blank rectangle under the menu item and do not open up into a sub-menu display. Restarting Nautilus doesn't work and neither does reinstalling.